# WPF C# - Making a stack panel inside user control visible from parent

Tags: wpf, button, binding, user-controls, parent-child

So I've seen similar questions asked on here, but haven't been able to nail this down.  We have a page that contains a UserControl where a StackPanel inside it is hidden onload, and the parent has a button that needs to make a StackPanel (`stkSomePanel` in UserControl1.xaml) inside the UserControl visible when initially clicked (we want to hide it, onload - the code has most of the values as `Visible`, for now, so we can see it and try to hide it - part of the problem is knowing where to put `.Hidden` and `.Visible`, too).  The button text must change from "Edit" to "Save".  When clicked again, the visibility of the StackPanel needs to toggle back to hidden and the text back to "Edit".

Should be a simple concept, but not clear how to bind what to what.  I have a button on the parent that I'm trying to use to click a child button I'd intend to hide, but not sure I even need the child button.  I've tested variations of this where I could click the child button and it would update the button text of the child button and the visibility of the child StackPanel one time, indicating it runs `ClickHereExecuted()`, but that's just a one-time set, not a toggle, and nothing happens at all if I click the parent button, which is really what needs to work.

So far, MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:MyProject"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyProject.UserControls"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
>
    <StackPanel>
        <v:GreatUserControl x:Name="UC1" />
        <Button Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" Command="{Binding ClickHereCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static RoutedCommand ClickHereCommand {get; set;}

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="MyProject.GreatUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibiltyConverter x:Key="ConvBoolToVis"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Button Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" Command="{Binding ClickHereCommand}" />
    <StackPanel x:Name="stkSomePanel" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Visibility="{Binding vis, ElementName=UserControl1, Converter={StaticResource ConvBoolToVis}}">
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
namespace MyProject.UserControls
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Visibility vis
        {
            get { return (Visibility)GetValue(VisibilityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VisibilityProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty VisiblityProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("vis", typeof(Visibility), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));

        public string ButtonContent
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonContent", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public RoutedCommand ClickHereCommand
        {
            get { return (RoutedCommand)GetValue(ClickHereCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ClickHereCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ClickHereCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ClickHereCommand", typeof(RoutedCommand), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ClickHereCommand = new RoutedCommand();
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ClickHereCommand, ClickHereExecuted));            
            ButtonContent = "Edit";
        }

        public void ClickHereExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonContent = "Save";
            vis = Visibility.Visible;
        }


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: If It got you correctly, you want a Button in Window, and StackPanel in UC. This StackPanel should hide, when Button in Window is clicked ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan More accurately, the button would show the hidden StackPanel in the UC, and hide it again when clicked again.  The text would change from "Edit" (default) to "Save", and show the StackPanel.  When clicked again, "Save" becomes "Edit" and the StackPanel is hidden again.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found I could do this without binding, without a `DependencyProperty`, without a `get-set`, no Boolean converters, no `StaticResources`, no `Command`.  Just a good-ol' fashioned `Click` EventHandler.  I just wasn't sure of how to access the objects inside the child (UserControl) without doing a binding, because everything on the internet I found says to use those things and do bindings.  **THIS WAS *SO* NOT NEEDED!!!**  I wasted *SO* much time on all that, and there's NOTHING on the internet that I found that said I could do it any differently.

Basically, to get at any child control, you just have to have a name set on the UserControl, which I set to UC1:

```
<v:GreatUserControl x:Name="UC1" />
```

My MainWindow's button now looks like this:

```
<Button Content="Edit" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
```

Then, in my MainWindow's code-behind, onload, I make the StackPanel on the child hidden with a "dot" syntax off of `UC1`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UC1.stkSomePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have a function `btnEdit_Click` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` where I reference the StackPanel the same way:

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnEdit = (Button)sender;
    string btnText = btnEdit.Content.ToString();

    if (btnText == "Edit")
    {
        UC1.stkSomePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        btnEdit.Content = "Save";
    }
    else
    {
        UC1.stkSomePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnEdit.Content = "Edit";
    }
}
```

This is all the code I needed.

Comment: Even though it's been a long time, I will comment on this, so that people don't use your solution for serious projects, because it teaches bad practices.

Your solution might be simpler, but it violates the MVVM principles. Changing the text of the button could be considered logic, which should be in the view model instead.

Comment: @gabrielkerekes Would love to see your solution, then, but for us, we weren't even using models/views.  It was another page we were importing in as a UserControl.  I was beating my head against a wall trying to do it "the real way" - see Ed Plunkett's answer and my comments.  It was a lot of mumbo-jumbo to adhere to principles that weren't even able to accomplish what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button 
    Content="{Binding ButtonContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
    Command="{Binding ClickHereCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
    />
<StackPanel 
    x:Name="stkSomePanel" 
    Visibility="{Binding vis, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource ConvBoolToVis}}"
    >
```

`ElementName=UserControl1` would work, IIRC, if the `UserControl` element at the root of your user control XAML had `x:Name="UserControl1"`: `ElementName="Foo"` means "the element in scope which has an `x:Name` attribute equal to 'Foo'". And I haven't done it recently, but my recollection is that there's no special case there for the root element of the file (why would there be, right?) so it should work.

But anyway, all these bindings are resolved in the same context, and in each case you're binding to a property of your `UserControl` subclass, so they'd all use the same source.

You can add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to any `Binding`, and get lots of debug info in your `Output` pane in VS, showing what it's doing to resolve the source for the `Binding`, and where it fails if it does fail. Great stuff, very handy.

```
<Button 
    Content="{Binding ButtonContent, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
    Command="{Binding ClickHereCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
    />
```

Comment: Thanks - good stuff, indeed, but got tired of all the binding stuff. It really isn't intuitive to me what's going on under-the-covers in order to then manipulate what is being set into something useful, i.e. If the button's command is bound to StackPanel visibility, how does it then change the text? If the button's command is bound to text, how does it change the visibility? And to switch it back again? And then to set the SP visibility - is it using the button's visibility? Setting it in the `DependencyProperty` or onload of the window/control is easy-not so to something different on-the-fly.

Comment: @vapcguy The command's execute method would set both the `vis` and `ButtonContent` properties. There's a steep learning curve with this stuff doing it "the Right Way", but the "wrong way" is very limited and unsuitable for nontrivial development. I hated WPF with a purple passion for the first year or more I worked with it, even after I started to get my head around it. It's like moving from procedural programming to OOP: You're learning a new way of thinking about things, and the value of the new way is not obvious until you start to get a foothold in it.

Comment: @vapcguy I mean, your Click event will, obviously, do exactly what you want to do here. It's sufficient for your current needs. I wouldn't throw a fit if somebody I work with checked in that code. However, in my experience that way of doing things doesn't scale well to much more complicated code.

Comment: @ EdPlunkett Yeah-agreed, and why I was trying to do it the "right way", but it just didn't seem feasible. I mean, what would `vis` and `ButtonContent` actually get set to? The default values I gave either the `Visibility` and `Content` properties of the button? The values in the `DependencyProperty` `Register` command?  And then how can they get updated? I understand databinding, like a DataTable to a GridView, for instance, and it seems like that's what is happening-binding to one object with another's properties.  But then you can't change it on-the-fly, like I was attempting to do, right?

Comment: @vapcguy They'd start with the defaults, then you can have them change by binding to something else that changes for whatever reason. Or you can change a viewmodel property from a command execute method: When your `ClickHereExecuted` executes, the stack panel will appear and the button will change its contents to "Save". That's the point of the whole thing -- if you couldn't do that, it would all be a waste of time.

Comment: Yeah, I could get that far with the child button - never could with the parent button.  But I couldn't then click it again and get it to reset back to "Edit" and make the panel disappear again.

Comment: @vapcguy Oh, OK. For that you could have a private bool flag that says which state it's in, and ClickHereExecuted  would go either way according to the flag, and then flip the flag for next time. Or else make the flag the public property, ClickHereExecuted just toggles the flag, and have style triggers in the XAML that update visibility, button text, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123815/discussion-between-ed-plunkett-and-vapcguy).